# Git - Save Work in Progress -- Changes Missing After Branching

Tags: git

I'm trying to save my changes, using Git, before actually doing a push. This is so I don't lose my work if my system crashes.

I looked into `git stash`, which seems nice, but it appears that's just local, so that doesn't help.

I read that I should create a new branch and push that. Well, that's what I did, below, and when I went back to the master branch, my working files were no longer showing up.

I have two questions:

> What did I do wrong?
>
> Is there a better way to save changes before you're ready to push?

My attempt:

// In master, where I have work in progress, create and move to a new branch

```
git checkout -b branch1
```

// Stage, then push, the changes in the new branch

```
git add .

git commit -m "committing changes from new local branch"

git push
```

> fatal: The current branch branch1 has no upstream branch.

// Create remote branch and push new local branch to it (changes now on server)

```
git push --set-upstream origin branch1
```

// Go back to master to work

```
git checkout master
```

**// Uh oh, changes aren’t showing up back in master? Where did they go?**

```
git status
```

> On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: You didn't merge into master, please explain what you're trying to accomplish. You have committed and pushes your changes to a separate branch, then you switched back to master, which is exactly how you left master the last time you were on it. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: I'm simply trying to save my work in progress. If my changes take a day or two to make, I'd like to save them in the meantime to guard against losing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong.  Your changes, which were in the Git stage, were committed on `branch1` and pushed to the server.  Hence, after you did that commit, the stage was cleaned.

To get back the changes from `branch1` into `master`, you can try merging `branch1` into `master`, e.g.

```
git checkout master
git merge branch1
```

I find it odd that you are working directly on the `master` branch.  More typically, you would already be working on some feature branch `branch1` and then be looking to merge the entire feature back into `master` at a later point.  I mention this scenario, because it would allow a much smoother operation.  You could make a *temporary* commit on `branch1`, then push.  When you return to work, you can keep working, and then *amend* the commit via:

```
git commit --amend
```

Now, you would be on your feature branch with a single commit containing all the work you had intended to do.

Comment: To be clear, I'm working in master in my sandbox/test area. For my actual work, I'm really on a branch. Back in my sandbox, I wanted to see how to make changes (which I did in master), and save them on the server without pushing the original branch on which I was working. It's just unfortunate that I show it as master here.

Comment: I did `git merge branch1` and git shows: 7 files changed, 4 insertions(+). However, a `git status` on master shows: Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. nothing to commit, working tree clean. So I don't see my changes to pick up where I left off.

Comment: @BobHorn If you are paranoid and want a way to protect your work remotely (rather than only locally through a commit), then making a temporary commit and pushing it is a good way to go.

Comment: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit` ... this just means that your local `master` branch is now 1 commit ahead of `origin/master`, which is your local remote tracking branch (confusing? yes it is).

Comment: Is it really paranoid, or just good software practice? I mean, I don't want to lose a day of work. Haven't we all been there? I haven't heard of a "temporary commit." I'll have to check into that. I thought commits were also local, and the only way it got back to the server was via push.

Comment: @BobHorn I am using the term "temporary" commit just to mean a regular commit which you however intend to amend later on.  If you have a private branch, you can amend your latest commit when you return the next day to finish the feature.  But in the meantime, your current day's work was safe and sound on the repo.

Comment: Isn't a commit a local operation? If so, that doesn't save my changes on the server. Also, I'm not saying my way is how it should be done. I just want to save my work before doing a push. Certainly folks in the git community have solved this issue, no? I mean, I can't imagine people keeping working only locally for days, with the possibility of losing it all.

Comment: @BobHorn Um...maybe you are not reading my comments, or are misunderstanding everything I have been saying.  You _commit_ locally, in a temporary sense, and then _push_ that commit to the remote.  _Your work is now on the remote_, but the feature may be incomplete.  You come to work tomorrow morning, finish the job, then do `git commit --amend` to patch up that commit.

Comment: Ok, so don't worry about making a branch of a branch to save my work. Just go ahead and push (in whatever branch I'm working in), even if my changes aren't ready. Then I can `git commit --amend` later. That's what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, but you only get away with that if you're the only one working on the branch.  If it's a branch you're sharing with several other people, and there is any chance they could commit between now and when you finish the job, then you can't use this trick.  In that case, you'd have to use a temporary branch.  In my experience, I don't end up branching very often to just backup my work, so I think my suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Agreed. I read a suggestion online that making a branch of a branch, to backup the work, was the way to go. I think that's more trouble than it's worth. Since I'll mostly be working alone in a branch, I can just push often. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`master` is the name of the default branch.  You created a new branch, which is based off `master`, and committed your changes there.  That branch now contains all the commits that were in `master`, plus the new commit.  You then pushed the new branch to the remote.  All good so far.

You then switched back to `master`.  Why?  That doesn't contain what you were working on.  Your new branch contains what you were working on.  Carry on working on that branch.  When you have completed that part of your work, merge it back into `master`.

Also: Stop thinking of using Git as "saving".  It's a way to record and communicate changes to a codebase over time.  It's not a fancy way of saving.  That's a common mistake beginners make.

Comment: master *did* contain what I was working on. Think of that as my initial branch. It's only master in this example because that's my test/sandbox area where I was trying to save my changes. I created a branch to simply save my changes, then go back to master and keep working.

Comment: When I say save, I'm talking about getting a copy of my work on the server so I don't lose it in the event of a crash. The only way work gets to the server with Git is a push, right? So a commit won't help. In the Git community, how do folks save their work in progress before pushing it?

Comment: @BobHorn They push it to the remote, that is how they do it.  You could of course backup your working directory to some other storage, e.g. a thumb drive or Google Drive, but that isn't necessary with Git.

Comment: I think the problem is the confusion in my initial post. People helping me (like you) assumed that master was master. That's my bad. I was only using master to test things. I was treating it like a branch. So where you see master, pretend that's a branch I'm working on. I simply wanted to save my work on the server before I was ready to do a push. In TFS, you can do this with a shelveset. Your changes are on the server, but not in the branch.